# How do you strip newline from file lines?

Tags: python-3.x, file, generator, newline, strip

Below is the code to read a file and return contents without comments and join lines that end with '//'.

```
def get_lines(path: str) -> Iterator[str]:

    """ Function to print lines of a given file and remove comments"""

    output: str = ''
    with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as filehandle:
        lines: get_lines = filehandle.readline()
        for lines in filehandle:
    
            if lines.startswith('#'):
                while lines.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
                    next_line = next(filehandle)
                    lines = lines.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line
               continue
            else:
        
                while lines.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
                    next_line = next(filehandle)
                    lines = lines.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line
                output += lines
                output = lines.split("#",1)
                lines = output[0].strip('\n')
        
            while lines.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
                next_line = next(filehandle)
                lines = lines.rstrip()[:-1] + next_line
                lines.strip('\n')
    
            yield lines
    
g = get_lines('C:\\Users\Swayam\Documents\ok2.txt')
for x in g:
    x.strip('\n')
    print (x)
```

Below is the file I am working on:

```
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line0>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line1># comment
<line2>
# this entire line is a comment - don't include it in the output
<line3.1 \ #world 
line3.2 \
line3.3>
<line4.1 \ 
line4.2>
<line5># comment \
# more comment1 \
more comment2>
<line6>
# here's a comment line continued to the next line \
this line is part of the comment from the previous line
```

Below is the output of this code:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>

<line4.1 line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

Expected output:

```
<line0>
<line1>
<line2>
<line3.1 line3.2 line3.3>
<line4.1 line4.2>
<line5>
<line6>
```

How do I strip this newline? I have added strip in almost all parts of the code but clearly does not work.

Comment: you need to assign the result of `lines.strip('\n')` in the last while loop back to lines, like `lines = lines.strip('\n')`

Comment: That works, thank you for your input.